# How to make Unit test for my Controller-Service-Repository methods in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I want to test methods in my Controller-Service-Repository pattern, especially index method

ChecklistsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1;

use App\Exceptions\NotFoundException;
use App\Exceptions\NotImplementedException;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreChecklistsRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateChecklistRequest;
use App\Services\ChecklistsServiceInterface;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChecklistController extends BaseApiV1Controller
{
    private $_checklistsService;

    public function __construct(ChecklistsServiceInterface $checklistService) {
        $this->_checklistsService = $checklistService;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        return $this->_checklistsService->getUserChecklists($user['userId']);
    }
}
```

ChecklistService.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\Checklist;
use App\Repositories\ChecklistsRepositoryInterface;

class ChecklistsService implements ChecklistsServiceInterface
{
    private $_checklistsRepository;

    public function __construct(ChecklistsRepositoryInterface $checklistsRepository)
    {
        $this->_checklistsRepository = $checklistsRepository;
    }

    public function getUserChecklists(int $userId)
    {
        return $this->_checklistsRepository->getUserChecklists($userId);
    }
}
```

ChecklistRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Checklist;

class ChecklistsRepository implements ChecklistsRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getUserChecklists(int $userId)
    {
        return Checklist::where('userId', $userId)->get();
    }
}
```

So i want to make Unit tests for Index method in Controller and getUserChecklists methods in Service and Repository.

Comment: Please add a test you already tried. And specify what you want to test.

Comment: Just an FYI, according to [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) - 4.3 (and PSR-2  - 4.2) it's considered bad practice to add an `_` to the beginning of a property name to indicate it's `private`. Obviously, it's your code, you're free to do whatever :) I just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: Normally when unit testing you'd mock all dependencies and test whether the class under test behaves the way it should when the dependencies behave in a predictable way . Have you attempted doing this at all? Note that unit testing controller methods is not recommended because it does not really tell you much due to how the request lifecycle is.

Comment: And in the Laravel community feature testing is the standard. due to it having a lot of helper functionality in the test classes so you don't have to mock anything in laravel

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides [HTTP testing helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests). These will allow you to make assertions on the response of your controller methods.

Example:

```php
public function test_index_route {

    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $response = $this->actingAs($user) // index method requires a user
             ->get('/');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
        ->assertJsonCount($expectedResultCount);
        ->assertJson($expectedStructure);
}
```

Since some tests will require database records existing, use [Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-model-factories) to create your desired database state. Also, be sure to check out the full list of available assertions for both the [HTTP](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#response-assertions) and [Database](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#available-assertions) helpers.

Comment: It is not a unit test

Comment: @Rashad Although the title specifies unit test, the asker would like to test the `index` method which is a controller route. This can be tested at the feature level.